# need photo of website on Blackberry for a test

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10

I need a big favor from a blackberry user/s. I need a photo of the homepage of the following website. It can be any blackberry phone. The person I setup the site for has to send the site to potential clients that have blackberrys. I'd like to see how it look on any blackberry. I tried running simulators but I'm not having luck getting the http to work.

Thanks in advance for any help.
http://ensenadahondavillas.com

Here a an example from my samsung galaxy 4.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByD1b7-BBd6LdVFfX3VUOFNOTW8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: [Here, right off Z10](http://www.file.si/1z6Z639TUpxonuN/screens.zip)

Answer (score 4):

The best thing to do, is to use an emulator. You can check your website in a Blackberry very easily following [this guide for an Blackberry emulator](http://www.cantoni.org/2007/12/18/blackberrysimulator). Using Google and you'll find emulators for Android and iOS as well.

Hope I could help you.

Comment: You're right. I just got one emulator going and was able to view the site on an blackberry 9630 (a 2009 phone). It shows the site as it would look on a desktop. The blackberry 10 version require a lengthy setup and Virtual PC. If anyone could contribute a photo from a Blackberry 10 it would be greatly appreciated.